# How to pass new data from one page to another page when using Angular HttpClient and InMemoryDbService?

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried adding a new position on the "Positions" page,[image]

and it appeared in the position list.[image]

But, I am not sure how to make the new position appear in the dropdown list on the "Employees" page.[image]

Here's what I've done so far.

in-memory-data-service.ts

```
...

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const employees = [
      { id: 'abc1', name: 'abc', position: 'Manager'},
      { id: 'abc2', name: 'def', position: 'Manager'},
      { id: 'abc3', name: 'ghi', position: 'Developer'},
      { id: 'abc4', name: 'jkl', position: 'Consultant'},
      { id: 'abc5', name: 'mno', position: 'Developer'},
      { id: 'abc6', name: 'pqr', position: 'IT Intern'}
    ];
    const positions = [
      { position: 'Manager'},
      { position: 'Developer'},
      { position: 'Consultant'},
      { position: 'IT Intern'}
    ];
    return {employees, positions};
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

employeePosition.services.ts

```
...
export class employeePositionService {

  private positionsUrl = 'api/positions';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployeePositions(): Observable<employeePosition[]> {
    return this.http.get<employeePosition[]>(this.positionsUrl).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched positions')),
      catchError(this.handleError<employeePosition[]>('getEmployeePositions', []))
    );
  }

  addEmployeePosition(position: employeePosition): Observable<employeePosition> {
    return this.http.post<employeePosition>(this.positionsUrl, position, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newPosition: employeePosition) => this.log(`added position with id=${newPosition}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<employeePosition>('addEmployeePosition'))
    );
  }
...
```

positions.component.html

```
...
<!-- Positions table -->
<tr *ngFor="let employeePosition of employeePositions; let i = index" scope="row">
        <td class="text-center">
          {{ employeePosition.position }}
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <button mdbRipple type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
             (click)="editPosition(employeePosition, i)" >Edit</button>&nbsp;
          <button mdbRipple type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
             (click)="deletePosition(employeePosition, i, employeePositions)" >Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
...
```

positions.component.ts

```
...
employeePosition: employeePosition | undefined;
employeePositions: employeePosition[] = [];
...
getEmployeePositions(): void {
  this.employeePositionService.getEmployeePositions()
   .subscribe(employeePositions => this.employeePositions = employeePositions);
}

addPosition(size: string = ''): void {
  this.modalRefAdd = this.modalService.open(AddPositionFormComponent, {
    modalClass: size,
    data: {}
  });

  this.modalRefAdd.onClose.subscribe(res => {
    if(res != null) {
      this.employeePositions = [...this.employeePositions, res];
    } else {
      close();
    }
  });
}
```

add-position-form.component.html

```
<!-- Create New Position Modal -->
<div id="add-employee-position">
  <div class="modal-header evonik white-text">
      <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Create New Position</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRefAdd.close()"><span aria-hidden="true" style="color: #000000;">×</span></button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body m-0 p-50">
      <form [formGroup]="positionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group pb-1">
              <label>Position:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="class form-row pb-3">
              <div class="class col">
                  <mdb-form-control>
                      <input mdbValidate mdbInput type="text" formControlName="position" class="form-control" required>
                      <label mdbLabel class="form-label">Enter a new position here</label>
                      <mdb-error *ngIf="position?.invalid && (position?.dirty || position?.touched)">New position is required</mdb-error>
                  </mdb-form-control>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-footer mt-1">
      <button mdbRipple type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="modalRefAdd.close()">Cancel</button>
      <button mdbRipple type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Confirm</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

add-position-form.component.ts

```
...
onSubmit() {
    this.positionForm.markAllAsTouched();
    if(this.positionForm.invalid) {
      return
    } else {
      const data = this.positionForm.value;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.position);
      this.employeePositionService.addEmployeePosition({position: data.position} as 
      employeePosition).subscribe(result => {
        this.employeePositionService.getEmployeePositions().subscribe(results => console.log(results))
      });

      this.modalRefAdd.close(data);
    }
  }
...
```

add-user-form.component.html

```
...
   <!-- Create New Employee Modal (position part) -->
   <div class="form-group pt-2 pb-1">
      <label>Employee position:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <mdb-form-control>
         <mdb-select mdbValidate [multiple]="false" formControlName="position" required>
            <mdb-option *ngFor="let employeePosition of employeePositions" >
               {{ employeePosition.position }}
            </mdb-option>
         </mdb-select>
         <label mdbLabel class="form-label">Select position</label>
         <mdb-error *ngIf="position?.invalid && (position?.dirty || position?.touched)">Position is required</mdb-error>
      </mdb-form-control>
   </div>
...
    
   <div class="modal-footer mt-1">
      <button mdbRipple type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="modalRefAdd.close()">Cancel</button>
      <button mdbRipple type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Confirm</button>
   </div>
```

add-user-form.component.ts

```
  get position(): AbstractControl {
     return this.userForm.get('position')!;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
     this.getEmployeePositions();
  }

  getEmployeePositions(): void {
     this.employeePositionService.getEmployeePositions()
       .subscribe(employeePositions => this.employeePositions = employeePositions);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.userForm.markAllAsTouched();
    if(this.userForm.invalid) {
      return
    } else {
      const data = this.userForm.value;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.id);
      this.employeeService.addEmployee({id : data.id, name: data.name, position: data.position} as Employee).subscribe(result => {
        this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(results => console.log(results))
      });
  
      this.modalRefAdd.close(data);
    }
  }
```

I hope someone can assist me with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would like to know a sample data you are getting in addEmployeePosition and getEmployeePositions API. I guess you are not getting right data from Backend

Comment: The data that I am getting is in the api/positions, which is the const positions in the in-memory-data-service.ts file.

Comment: Can you put also the Create Employee modal src?

Comment: @heshzack in the add-position-form.component.ts file you are printing the results in the console right? Are you getting the updated list in it?

Comment: @ZsoltBalint I have put the codes for the Create Employee Modal.

Comment: @GouthamHarshith no, unfortunately. The new position was classified as an object instead of an array like the const positions in the in-memory-data.service.ts file.

Array(4)
0: {position: 'Manager'}
1: {position: 'Developer'}
2: {position: 'Consultant'}
3: {position: 'IT Intern'}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Object
position: "abc"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Hmm, cannot see it. Why am i asking this, is that to see how are you passing those options to the dropdown, because when you open the modal those option need to be fetch again to have reflect the latest values.

Comment: @ZsoltBalint sorry I pasted the wrong code before. I have put the correct code for the Create Employee modal.

Comment: After you create a new position, you need to trigger a new getEmployeePositions, to refresh employeePositions. Are you already doing this:  this.employeePositionService.getEmployeePositions().subscribe(results => console.log(results)). But just logging into console.

Comment: @ZsoltBalint the thing is, I'm not sure how do I add the data from the modal to the const positions array in the in-memory-data.service.ts.

Comment: If you configured ok, like this: @NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { delay: 500 })
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }

Answer (score 0):

You pass only the `position` property to your backend, ie.

```
this.employeePositionService.addEmployeePosition({position: data.position} as
```

while returning the whole data object when closing your dialog, ie

```
this.modalRefAdd.close(data);
```

Which probably leads to the wrong object being added to the array here

```
this.modalRefAdd.onClose.subscribe(res => {
    if(res != null) {
      this.employeePositions = [...this.employeePositions, res];
    } else {
      close();
    }
  });
```

You don't seem to be updating your list after sending another `position` to your backend, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: I tried to put this.modalRefAdd.close(data.position); in in-memory-data-service.ts file, but the input does not come out in the table, only the row. I just want to know how can I pass the new position to the array.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer for this question. I need to give an id to the positions array and use an increment for the id in the `addEmployeePosition()` method.

in-memory-data.service.ts

```
positions: [
    { id: 1, position: 'Manager'},
    { id: 2, position: 'Developer'},
    { id: 3, position: 'Consultant'},
    { id: 4, position: 'IT Intern'}
  ]
```

employeePosition.service.ts

```
addEmployeePosition(position: employeePosition): Observable<employeePosition> {
  position.id = position.id + 1;
  return this.http.post<employeePosition>(this.positionsUrl, position, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((newPosition: employeePosition) => this.log(`added position with id=${newPosition}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<employeePosition>('addEmployeePosition'))
  );
}
```